# SQL select distinct "from" and "to" Cities

Tags: sql, select, case, distinct

Given below travel table, the from_city and to_city have duplicate entries.

| from_city | to_city | distance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NYC | BOS | 300 |
| BOS | NYC | 300 |
| OKC | BOS | 600 |

Write a query to retrieve only unique combinations as below -

| from_city | to_city | distance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NYC | BOS | 300 |
| OKC | BOS | 600 |

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have no other duplicates, you can use:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.from_city < t.to_city or
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.from_city = t.to_city and
                        t2.to_city = t.from_city
                 );
```

That is, select rows where they are ordered alphabetically.  Or select rows where the inverse row does not exist.